# Алгоритм удаления дублей

Tags: алгоритм

Есть список такого вида:

```
http://site.com/index.php?id=1
http://site.com/index.php?id=2
http://site.com/index.php?id=3
http://site.com/index.php?id=1&param=a
http://site.com/index.php?id=1&param=b
http://site2.com/index.php?id=3
http://site2.com/index.php?id=4
http://site2.com/index.php?id=5
http://site2.com/index.php?id=1&param=x
http://site2.com/index.php?id=1&param=y
http://site2.com/index.php?id=3&param=z
```

Требуется привести его к виду:

```
http://site.com/index.php?id=1
http://site.com/index.php?id=1&param=a
http://site2.com/index.php?id=3
http://site2.com/index.php?id=1&param=x
```

То есть удалить ссылки, где отличаются только значения параметров, но сами параметры одинаковы.
Посоветуйте по какому алгоритму лучше пойти и как бы это все попроще реализовать?

Answer (score 3):

предлагаю такой алгоритм. Для каждой строки делаем такое преобразование:

- отрезаем хвост по знаку вопроса
- разделяем на подстроки по &
- с полученного массива строк удаляем значения, оставив только ключи.
- сортируем ключи
  -собираем строку назад (без параметров).

То есть, было так `http://site.com/index.php?id=1&param=a`, станет так `http://site.com/index.php?id&param`

Все, теперь можно поудалять дубликаты стандартным способом через хеш.

Answer (score 1):

Долой велосипеды на регулярках! Есть же класс, который умеет парсить из коробки, почему бы не взять его?

(Нужно подключить `System.Web` для `HttpUtility`.)

```
// взяли весь текст
var raw = @"http://site.com/index.php?id=1
            http://site.com/index.php?id=2
            http://site.com/index.php?id=3
            http://site.com/index.php?id=1&param=a
            http://site.com/index.php?id=1&param=b
            http://site2.com/index.php?id=3
            http://site2.com/index.php?id=4
            http://site2.com/index.php?id=5
            http://site2.com/index.php?id=1&param=x
            http://site2.com/index.php?id=1&param=y
            http://site2.com/index.php?id=3&param=z";

var values =
    // разбили на строки
    from uriString in raw.Split(new[] { ' ', '\n', '\r' },
                                StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    // спарсили Uri
    let uri = new Uri(uriString)
    // спарсили Query String, положили ключи в HashSet
    let keys = new HashSet<string>(
            HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(uri.Query).Keys.Cast<string>())
    // объединили те, у кого сайт и адрес один и тот же
    group new { uri, keys } by new { uri.Host, uri.AbsolutePath };

// для сравнения множеств нужен компаратор
var comparer = HashSet<string>.CreateSetComparer();

// каждую группу группируем по одинаковым наборам ключей,
// из каждой подгруппы берём одного представителя
var mergedGroups = values.Select(g => g.GroupBy(uk => uk.keys, comparer)
                                       .Select(gg => gg.First()));

// всё соединяем в одну последовательность, выкидываем
// ключи, которые больше не нужны
var sampleUris = mergedGroups.SelectMany(g => g.Select(uk => uk.uri));

// выводим для контроля
foreach (var u in sampleUris)
    Console.WriteLine(u);
```

Результат:

```
http://site.com/index.php?id=1
http://site.com/index.php?id=1&param=a
http://site2.com/index.php?id=3
http://site2.com/index.php?id=1&param=x
```

Comment: А если не .NET? :)

Comment: @andreycha: Автор не указал платформу :) Надеюсь, он может перенести алгоритм на другой язык самостоятельно. Регулярки ведь тоже не во всех языках есть.

Answer (score 0):

[Первый RegEx](https://regex101.com/r/eX4uJ1/1) бъёт на домен и строку параметров

```
/http:\/\/(?<domain>[^\/\n]+)\/[^\?\n]+[?](?<params>[^\n]+)/g
```

[Второй](https://regex101.com/r/cN2oT5/1) бъёт строку параметров на имена параметров

```
/(?:([^=&]+)[=][^&]+)/g
```

Далее смотрим есть ли совпадения с уже найденными строками, если есть то пропускаем строку и идем далее